# Mouse & touchpad sensitivity settings have no effect - Xubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I will start by saying that I'm completely new to Linux, so bear with me please.

I saw other questions on different sites but either there was no answer, or I didn't understand it.

I'm on a Asus ROG GL502VS-GZ427T at work and Xubuntu 16.04.3 is installed. It's a fresh installed, the laptop is a few days old. In the mouse & touchpad settings, I cannot adjust mouse OR touchpad sensitivity. It does nothing. My mouse is a Razer Taipan.

It is probably a matter of drivers but I have no idea where to start looking...

Help would but much appreciated

EDIT: I managed to change the touchpad sensitivity using `xinput --set-prop 18 "Synaptics Finger" 50 80 257`, so it works in command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

The above command helped me with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` solved the problem for me.